# Leaflet Sidebar V2 set default to open

Tags: javascript, leaflet, sidebar

I'm using Leaflet's Sidebar V2 plugin and it's working great, but I would like to have it open by default. So when the page loads, the sidebar is open but can be collapsed rather than the other way around.
Is there a way this can be done?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just after you add the sidebar to the map, use the method `open()`.

The argument of the method is the name of the tab.

```
var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar').addTo(map);

sidebar.open('home');
```